# Latest Date from Attendance Sheet where attendance is noted as "P"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of names in Column A starting in cell A2

Each column heading starting from cell B1 contains individual dates

As a person attends an event I enter P into the appropriate cell correlating to the person + date. If they don't attend the cell is left blank.

For example if person 1 attends on the first date I enter P into cell B2

How to I find the most recent date that the person attended for each person in column A?

Comment: *How to I find the most recent date* Most recent == last in the row? I'd recommend to use UDF, where statement like `Range("A2").EntireRow.Find(What:="P",SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Address` will give you the address of the last cell containing 'P' char in the row #2 (may use .Column to obtain column number).

Comment: Could you just share some sample data with us!!

Comment: @NGB meanwhile you can try this one,, `{=MAX(IF($B2:$D2="P",IF($B2:$D2<>"",B$1:D$1)))}` ☺

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula to pick off the right most column with a P in it and then return the date in the header row that corresponds to this column.  It is set up to be used adjacent to the column.  If you want to use it in a separate table or for select names only, a modification to the layout and formula would be required.

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($B2:$D2)/($B2:$D2="P"),1))
```

[image]